# Image Resizing - Width 100% with Max Height

Tags: image, resize, width, css

I'm wondering if this is at all possible.

I have a content area, and I'm going to put a picture in it. If it is less then 800px high after being put in the container with width:100%, then I want it to stay there. If it is over 800px high after the width 100%, I want it to ignore the width:100% line and read the max-height line (or does something to shrink the percentage of the width) until it is less then 800px tall, while keeping it's aspect ratio.

Ex. I have a container width of 700px, the picture 600px wide by 400px tall, it'll show up at 700px wide x 500px tall because of the width:100%.

Ex. I have a container width of 700px, the picture is 400px wide x 600px tall. Right now it'll show up as 700px wide 900px tall with the width:100% code, but I'd like a piece of code that sees that it's over the max height of 800px tall, and thus triggers something so that the width:100% is ignored and instead goes off of the max-height:800px line, which would then make the picture 600px wide x 800px tall.

I can't put max-height and width:100% in the same element because then the aspect ratio isn't kept.

Comment: Providing code or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) will make your question much easier to answer

Comment: how do you put the image in the content area? You could use javascript / jquery to read the image size and manipulate your css.

Comment: It's for a forum, so the images would be placed in through comments.

Comment: Can't you just set `height: auto` and `width: 100%` on every image? This should keep your aspect ratio and automatically scale the image proportionally. I always try to make the browser do as much of the work for me as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do this with CSS. I tried doing it with some simple JS, which worked nicely:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
div {width: 700px; background: #e7e7e7;}
img {width: 100%;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div>
    <img src="600x400.jpg" >
    <br>
    <br>
    <img src="400x600.jpg">
</div>

<script>
window.onload = imgSizer;
function imgSizer() 
{
    "use strict";
    var d = document, imgs, i, ii;
    imgs = d.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (i=0, ii=imgs.length; i<ii; i+=1)
    {
        if (imgs[i].height > "800")
        {
            imgs[i].setAttribute("style", "height:800px; width: auto;");
        } else {
            imgs[i].style.maxWidth = "100%";
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm utterly new to JS, though, so there is probably a much better way to do this. You can also view the example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EsIBi

If you prefer, you could use a bit of jQuery to hep with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
#content {width: 700px; background: #e7e7e7;}
img {width: 100%;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
    <img src="http://pageaffairs.com/sp/so-16368859/600x400.jpg" >
    <br>
    <br>
    <img src="http://pageaffairs.com/sp/so-16368859/400x600.jpg">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgs = $("#content").children('img');
    for (var i=0, ii=imgs.length; i<ii; i+=1)
    {
        if (imgs[i].height > "800")
        {
            imgs[i].setAttribute("style", "height:800px; width: auto;");
        } else {
            imgs[i].style.maxWidth = "100%";
        }
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div img{   max-width: 100%; 
            max-height: 100%; 
        }
<div>
    <img src="">
</div>
```

With this tips you can to obtain container similar to facebook..
sorry I speak spanish...